# Google Colab Can't Open Large CSV File

Tags: csv, google-colaboratory, large-files

I have been trying to open a large .csv file in Google Colab for several hours now and keep getting the error:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on
>   source failed.

The code I'm using is:

```
path = "/content/drive/My Drive/data/big.csv"
#df_bonus = pd.read_csv(path, engine="python")
df_bonus = pd.read_csv(path)
```

Note: I've tried it without and without the engine="python" parameter. Using the engine="python" gives error

> [Errno 5] Input/output error

which seems to be connected to hidden quotas.

In the past, I've gotten this error occasionally but after trying a few times, have been able to read the file. However, this time, it's failed maybe 30 time in a row.

I have tried with and without the engine="python", using no accelerator, using GPU and using TPU. I have also gotten the message once that I needed more RAM and accepted more RAM.  However, I consistently am getting errors. Sometimes the error appears at once.  Other times it appears after about five minutes.

Can anyone suggest a way to get this to open and why it's not opening now? Could it be that Google is just very busy? Or why the intermittence and why now am I not able to read the file at all?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Why not try using the `chunksize` parameter? As a good practice for big files?

Comment: How would that work?  Can you suggest a place to read up on it?

Comment: Of course, here is a question regarding how to open a huge csv file, solved by using `chunksize`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas

Comment: Why do you think it worked without chunksize yesterday but not today?